# JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: spring, hibernate, playframework-2.0, one-to-one

I'm using the Play framework with Spring and Hibernate, and I get the following error when I try to save an entity containing a one-to-one relationship to another entity

```
[play] Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [org.famian.web.models.domains.StudyCriteria.ensatIdent]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [org.famian.web.models.domains.StudyCriteria.ensatIdent]
 [play]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
 [play]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
 [play]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
 [play]     at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
 [play]     at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
 [play] Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [org.famian.web.models.domains.StudyCriteria.ensatIdent]
 [play]     at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
 [play]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
 [play]     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
 [play]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
 [play]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
```

The 2 entities share a common primary key, below are my classes

```
@Entity
public class EnsatIdent implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EnsatIdentPK id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "ensatIdent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StudyCriteria studyCriteria;
}

@Entity
public class StudyCriteria {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EnsatIdentPK id;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "center_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ensat_id")
    })
    @OneToOne
    private EnsatIdent ensatIdent;
}

@Embeddable
public class EnsatIdentPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "center_id", columnDefinition = "varchar(5)")
    private String centerId;

    @Column(name = "ensat_id", columnDefinition = "int(11)")
    private Integer ensatId;
}
```

My service class is a class called IdenService which extending the Spring PagingAndSortingRepository class. When I save, I called

```
IdenService service.save(ensatIdent)
```

If I do a System.out.println() on

> ensatIdent.getStudyCriteria()

it shows

> StudyCriteria(id=EnsatIdentPK(centerId=GYMU, ensatId=3))

It saves fine if the entity only contain Ident information, but if I add studyCriteria in the object, the error will occur. I don't understand what is happening, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, the problem was because StudyCriteria object does not have a reference of the EnsatIden object.

By adding

```
ensatIdent.getStudyCriteria().setEnsatIdent(ensatIdent);
```

solved the error